# How to make an absolute positioned div inside relative div overflow on x and not y

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioned `div` in a relative positioned `div`. I want the inner `div` to overflow on the x-axis, but not on the y-axis.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: visible;
  }

  #wrapper div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    bottom: -25px;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get cropping or overflow with scrollbars in IE7, IE8, Firefox3, Chrome of the inner div on the x-axis which is not what I want.

I feel I must surely be doing something wrong. Is there a way to accomplish my requirements?

Comment: Turned out that what I was trying to do wasn't possible given html4 + css implementations at the time. An alternative approach was taken which did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was trying to do is not possible given html4 + css implementations at the time.
I needed to use an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the inner div to overflow on
>   the y-axis, but not on the x-axis.

You are using CSS for opposite, try putting this css in your inner div:

```
  #wrapper div {
    ............
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
```

And your parent div:

```
  #wrapper {
    ............
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Thnx for that. I corrected my css to reflect what I was trying :)

Comment: @vansllly: try putting `overflow: auto;` before overflow-y and x and set `overflow-y` to `scroll` rather than `visible` to see if it helps.

Comment: putting css on inner div doesn't seem to cause the behaviour I wanted. Setting overflow to scroll is not what I want, I want any overflow of the inner div to be invisible on the y-axis but visible on the x-axis.